# Multi-user python notebooks on server with conda env on local machine?

Tags: python, architecture, jupyter, jupyterhub

My team uses a system (call it ABC). ABC provides a python API but, due to licensing, it can only interface with ABC locally.

I would like to setup a remote environment that enables my team to collaborate via notebooks (hopefully JupyterHub), but executes the python code locally (we have identical conda environments on each of our machines).

I can think of some hacky ways to achieve this. But is there a canonical, or clean way of doing this that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried jupyterhub? It seems like you’re trying to host multiple jupyterlab users from a single machine, and that’s exactly what [the littlest jupyterhub](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/) does.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado, not quite. I want multiple users to be able to view and edit the same notebooks (hopefully simultaneously) but have the code run on their local machines

Comment: you want all users to be able to co-edit each other's notebooks, each hosted on their own machines? yeah that's not possible with any tool/service I know of.

Comment: you might have some luck using something like [vscode liveshare](https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share). it looks like [liveshare with notebooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/reference/notebooks) is currently in preview. that might be the closest thing to what you're looking for.

Comment: No, I want to host the notebooks and have the management of the collaborative editing on the server. Only the code is executed in the client machine